# Is there a way to dynamically change a listview's and it's items style

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I'm working on an application that has a few listview controls on a page (windows 10 desktop application).  We are using a gamepad to navigate between elements.
I'd like to be able to change the ListView (and it's items) style when it gets focus.  So that it's a style that's invert to the non focused style(s).  Then when my focus changes to the next style I want the listview that's losing focus to change it's styles back.

I've defined the 2 styles but am trying to figure out how to change the styles dynamically.

This of this as a metaphor.  My applications is primarily a dark theme.  All controls are 'muted' when you aren't interacting with them but when the control get's focus I want it to change to a lighter theme.

A listview is comprised of headers, items, footers and I want the whole set of styles to change as a unit.

I'm currently looking into hooking into the getting and losing focus events but I'm not sure that's the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

> when the control get's focus I want it to change to a lighter theme.

My understanding is that you want to change the theme of the control when the `ListView` gets/lost focus.

You can listen to the ListView's **GettingFocus** and **LostFocus** events.

Here is the code:

```xml
<ListView GettingFocus="ListView_GettingFocus" LostFocus="ListView_LostFocus">
    <!-- List items -->
</ListView>
```

```cs
private void ListView_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    (sender as ListView).RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
}

private void ListView_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ListView).RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
}
```

If you create the corresponding theme resource, this will meet your requirements.

Best regards.